# Faceted Search w/Lucene.NET & NHibernate.Search

Tags: nhibernate, lucene, nhibernate-search

Anyone know if it is possible to perform faceted searches with NHibernate.Search and Lucene.NET or do you need to implement something like Solr as well to get this functionality.

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: I think using Solr is easiest way to go. Are there a reason, you want to do it without?

Answer (score 1):

It's not built in, as far as I know.

This might be a way to go about it: http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/

But also SolrNet: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/
In combination with: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/NHibernateIntegration